# Do I have to account for every case of my enum Coding Keys?

Tags: json, swift, enums, decodable

I have 3 different URL's that I use to get my JSON from: 2 use the "snippet" parameter and 1 doesn't. The 3rd one crashes telling me that it has no "snippet" parameter but the first 2 don't have a "statistics" parameter and doesn't crash?

URL 1: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=(channelID)&maxResults=10&order=viewCount&key=(Constant.API_KEY)"

URL 2: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&forUsername=(channelName)&key=(Constant.API_KEY)"

URL 3: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=(videoID)&key=(Constant.API_KEY)"

Of note, I have confirmed that I am getting JSON back, it just crashes when the Model gets involved.

```
struct Video: Identifiable, Decodable {
    
    var id = UUID()
    var title = ""
    var thumbnail = ""
    var videoID = ""
    var publishedDate = ""
    var youtuber = ""
    
    var viewCount = ""
    var watched = false

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        
        case snippet
        case thumbnails
        case high
        case id
        case statistics
        
        case videoID = "videoId"
        case title
        case thumbnail = "url"
        case publishedDate = "publishedAt"
        case youtuber = "channelTitle"
        case viewCount
    }
    
    init (from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        
        let container =  try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let snippetContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .snippet)
        let thumbnailsContainer = try snippetContainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .thumbnails)
        let highContainer = try thumbnailsContainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .high)
        let idContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .id)
        let statisticsContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .statistics)
        
        self.title = try snippetContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
        self.thumbnail = try highContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .thumbnail)
        self.videoID = try idContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .videoID)
        self.publishedDate = try snippetContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .publishedDate)
        self.youtuber = try snippetContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .youtuber)
        self.viewCount = try statisticsContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .viewCount)
        
    }
}

Solution:

Used the “if container.contains(CodingKeys.statistics)” method, problem solved.
```

Comment: You need to provide a minimally reproducible example, otherwise it leads to the kind of back-and-forth that you saw with the answer below. What are the variations in the JSON that you receive (and please remove anything from the JSON/models that isn't related)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue can be resolved by simply setting properties under both containers as optional. Also, decode the values using `decodeIfPresent` method.

```
struct Video: Identifiable, Decodable {

    var id = UUID()
    var watched = false
    var videoID, title, thumbnail, youtuber, viewCount, publishedDate: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case snippet
        case thumbnails
        case high
        case id
        case statistics

        case videoID = "videoId"
        case title
        case thumbnail = "url"
        case publishedDate = "publishedAt"
        case youtuber = "channelTitle"
        case viewCount
    }

    init (from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        let container =  try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let snippetContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .snippet)
        let thumbnailsContainer = try snippetContainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .thumbnails)
        let highContainer = try thumbnailsContainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .high)
        let idContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .id)
        let statisticsContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .statistics)

        self.title = try snippetContainer.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .title)
        self.thumbnail = try highContainer.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .thumbnail)
        self.videoID = try idContainer.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .videoID)
        self.publishedDate = try snippetContainer.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .publishedDate)
        self.youtuber = try snippetContainer.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .youtuber)
        self.viewCount = try statisticsContainer.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .viewCount)
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the same result. I would have to make those enum cases optionals if that's even possible?

Comment: Still nothing, I started to play with decodeIfPresent, I feel like I'm getting closer. When I run URL 3 I get "no value found for key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"snippet\", intValue: nil)" and when I run URL 1 I get "no value found for key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"statistics\", intValue: nil)"

Comment: Still doesn't. More troubleshooting by commenting/uncommenting line by line revealed that the issue is that I have the statistics (or snippet) as a Key in my Enum. As soon as it tries to access the container, I'm done. I don't even reach the "decodeIfPresent" part, it stops before that

Comment: Post the `JSON` that you're trying to decode in your question.

Comment: Found a fix, posted in my post. Thanks for trying